# jquery 1.8.2 $(document).ready function fails to be called

Tags: jquery

I am having an issue where the code in the document.ready call is not executing.

```
$(document).ready(function () {
initializeControls();
});
```

I'm sure the jquery-1.8.2 script is loading and if switch out the 1.8.2 for the 1.4.4 script, everything works just fine.

Any ideas?

Comment: The problem is almost certainly in the `initializeControls` function. What does your JavaScript console say?

Comment: why dont you try `$(document).ready(function () {
alert("hello")
});`

Comment: Good call on checking the console.  That's the only place I haven't looked.  "no method 'curCSS'" which I believe was removed in 1.8.0.  I'm looking into it and will get back with what I find.

Comment: initializeControls is only performing one op.  $("input:button").button();

Comment: So this ended up being another script that was loaded that was bombing because of a removal of the curCSS alias.  I simply stepped through the code and couldn't find where this was occurring until I looked at the console.  It was in bright red.  Took a while to get the alias usage out.

Answer (score 2):

Try replacing the `$` with `jQuery`. It is possible that a plugin you are using has called the [noConflict](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.noConflict/) function and released the `$` variable.

Try

```
jQuery(document).ready(function () {
  initializeControls();
});
```

Answer (score 1):

You might want to check what's been deprecated between 1.4.4 and 1.8.2. Here's a fiddle with document load and 1.8.2 working http://jsfiddle.net/aRVtC/.

I've had issue with promises as in 1.8.2 no longer accepts an array of callbacks. Who knows what else `initializeControls()` could be doing.